# Basic Bash pipe tricks

Tags: bash

I'm going to run a short demonstration of Linux to an audience of 9-10 y.o children at school. I guess none has never seen a shell, so for the fun of them I'd like to show how many things you can achieve with a one-liner pipe. 
I'd like to start with:

```
echo "Hello world"
```

and then:

```
echo "Hello world" | figlet
echo "Hello world" | rev
echo "Hello world" | mail johndoe@gmail.com
```

Can you suggest me any one-liner that I can use with echo ?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: I don't understand the problem?

Comment: echo "Password" | kinit admin@REALM

Comment: echo "HELLO"  | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'   #tolowercase

Comment: (1) A simple shift cipher (a.k.a. Caesar\`s cipher): `echo "hello world" | tr m-za-m`

(2) Line to column: `echo "hello world" | fold -w1`

Comment: Thanks for the nice hacks you have shared!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have access to `netcat` (`nc`) and a browser you can do something like this:

`echo "Hello World!" | nc -l localhost 2888`

Then open your browser on `http://localhost:2888/` to see their message.

Comment: Thanks, that's extremely useful,not only for teaching purposes!

Answer (score 1):

Young dudes will also like:

```
echo "Hello Word" | espeak
```

You could try installing also the dictd dictionary which can be used to lookup offline words